# Different result between eclipse and text editor

Tags: java, eclipse

I use the following code to test the BouncyCastle crypto library:

```
import java.security.Security;

public class SimpleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String providerName="BC";

        if (Security.getProvider(providerName)==null)
        {
            System.out.println(providerName + "provider not installed");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(providerName + "is installed");
        }
    }
}
```

However, Eclipse shows "BCprovider not installed", and my EditPlus shows "BC is installed".

What makes this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library missing somewhere in your eclipse that it can not find it. You need to revise your configuration in eclipse.

Comment: Providers have to be registered. Of course, this means that they have to be in the classpath as well, but just putting them in the class path is not enough. So this is only a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference?
I guess different java runtimes may have different error messages.

IMHO, unless you check underlying JRE's are the same, the difference is not between Eclipse and texteditor, but between Java SE 7u7 and Java SE 6u35 (for example).

Anyway, that is not your actual problem, but effectively deploying the provider jar in your classpath and registering it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the difference is likely to be in the [static security provider configuration](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) in Java. You need to register providers somehow to be able to use them. If you cannot change the Java runtime, you can [register them dynamically](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) *if they have been signed properly*.